# Getting All hosts are taken by other resources with Nginx Ingress Controller

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have setup Nginx Controller as mentioned in the docs https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/. I have setup the Ingress with the below configuration

IngressClass

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  name: nginx
  # annotations:
  #   ingressclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
spec:
  controller: nginx.org/ingress-controller
```

Ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hn-service-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: hostnameservice.classpath.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /test
        backend:
          serviceName: hostname-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Below is the error when running the `describe` command. I am getting `All hosts are taken by other resources`

```
kubectl describe ingress hn-service-ingress
Name:             hn-service-ingress
Namespace:        pradeep
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host                           Path  Backends
  ----                           ----  --------
  hostnameservice.classpath.com
                                 /test    hostname-service:80 (100.96.1.12:8111,100.96.1.13:8111,100.96.2.13:8111)
Annotations:                     <none>
Events:
  Type     Reason    Age   From                      Message
  ----     ------    ----  ----                      -------
  Warning  Rejected  5s    nginx-ingress-controller  All hosts are taken by other resources
```

When I used to check with the `cafe` example, it is working fine. Where am I going wrong?

Note: I have configured the AWS load balancer and set the `/etc/hosts` to point to the `ELB` from AWS using the dnslookup.

Comment: I guess you have encounter [Host Collisions](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/handling-host-collisions/) Are you using another Ingress? If so could you share it?

Comment: I was able to resolve this. There was one more Ingress in another namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this is a bit old so hopefully OP was able to find a solution! I'm posting this answer as I believe one of the most common ways to end up in this situation is when you're using cert-manager. I'm sure many people have encountered this error, where you can create a non-SSL ingress resource just fine, but as soon as you create a TLS-based ingress resource with the cert-manager ingress shim, you encounter this error!

This is because cert-manager will create an additional ingress resource for you when attempting an HTTP challenge. It does this because the certificate authority has to have a way to access the file created by cert-manager to verify you own the domain, but SSL is not yet working, so it creates an ingress on your default port.

Here's an example of when I ran into this exact same thing:

```
NAME                        CLASS   HOSTS            ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
cm-acme-http-solver-6m9qm   nginx   isaacgentz.com             80        2s
isaac-site-ssl              nginx   isaacgentz.com             80, 443   4s
```

You can see that the hosts are the same, which is what nginx-ingress is complaining about.

**What's the solution**

Make sure you have the following annotation on your ingress resource:

```
acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
```

This will prevent cert-manager from creating a second ingress resource that conflicts!

Comment: What command are you using to get NAME / CLASS / HOSTS / ADDRESS / PORTS / AGE ?

Answer (score 6):

Please keep in mind that there are 3 types of `Nginx`. `Open Source Nginx Ingress Controller`, `Nginx Incorporaton` (nginx inc) and `Nginx Incorporaton Plus`.

As I mention in the comments, issue was casued by resources using the same `host`. It's called [Host Collisions](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/handling-host-and-listener-collisions/).

A host collision occurs when multiple resources configure the same host. The `Ingress Controller` supports two options for handling host collisions:

> - **Choosing the Winner**
>
> If multiple resources contend for the same host, the Ingress Controller will pick the winner based on the creationTimestamp of the resources: the oldest resource will win. In case there are more than one oldest resources (their creationTimestamp is the same), the Ingress Controller will choose the resource with the lexicographically smallest uid.
>
> - **Merging Configuration for the Same Host**
>
> It is possible to merge configuration for multiple Ingress resources for the same host. One common use case for this approach is distributing resources across multiple namespaces.

OP confirmed, that this was solved by changes made in another `Ingress` resource in another `namespace`.

> I was able to resolve this. There was one more Ingress in another namespace

Comment: docs.nginx.com has changed. New url: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/handling-host-and-listener-collisions/